# I want to redirect to a custom html page when new tab is created in chrome

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome

I am developing a chrome extension. I want to redirect to a custom html page when new tab is created.

This is process.js file.

```
    chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function() {
        alert("hello");
        window.open('https://ucsc.cmb.ac.lk/', '_self', false);
    });
```

This is manifest.json file.

```
    {
        "manifest_version": 2,
         "name": "xxx",
        "version": "1.0",
        "description": "xxx",
        "icons": {
            "128": "icon128.png",
            "48": "icon48.png",
            "16": "icon16.png"
        },
        "browser_action": {
            "default_icon": "icon16.png",
            "default_popup": "popup.html"
        },



        "background": {
            "scripts": ["process.js"],
            "presistent": true

        },

        "permissions": [
            "storage",
            "notifications",
            "contextMenus",
            "tabs",
            "activeTab",
            "http://*/",
            "https://*/"
        ]
    }
```

alert is working. but it is not loading the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for [Override Pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override).

Add this code to your manifest file:

```
"chrome_url_overrides" : {
   "pageToOverride": "myPage.html"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
window.open('https://ucsc.cmb.ac.lk/', '_blank', false);
```